Running a Redis cluster as a DaemonSet in Kubernetes so each node has all keys
Is it possible to host a Redis Sentinel cluster as a DaemonSet and have each node have all of the keys? And then setup a service that uses internalTrafficPolicy: Local to route pods to their respective Redis pod running on the same node?
All of the guides I've found are for a specific amount of pods or use a Helm chart. I would love for it to be a DaemonSet.
